# Plotting R0 against two parameters on a 3D plot with planes for certain R0 values

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics, graphics3d

I have been trying to replicate the following graph from the [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32834653/). The authors have plotted R0 on a 3D graph against the two parameters, gammaa and betas with two planes for R0=1 and R0=2.

[image]

The parameter values and the formula for R0 are given below.

```
betas = 0.274,
alphaa = 0.4775,
alphau = 0.695,
mu = 0.062,
qi = 0.078,
gammaa = 0.29,
etai = 0.009,
etau = 0.05

R0 = (betas*alphaa)/(gammaa+mu) + (betas*alphau*gammaa*(1-qi))/((gammaa+mu)*(etau+mu))
```

Any support on drawing this plot would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This just returns a number R0 which is 1.66322. Post the formula or your attempt to plot it here as Mathematica code that you've tried. We shouldn't have to look at the paper - the question should be self contained.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In fact, I linked the paper with the hope of crediting the source from which the graph was taken. So, you may not need to refer to the paper. I am very new to Mathematica and so I am still struggling trying to find my way around this problem. What I have understood so far is that all the parameters are set at the values given above, except gammaa and betas (varying from 0 to 0.4) which are considered as the independent variables of the function R0 which is now a two variable function, since the remaining parameters are fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- We should remove `betas = 0.274,alphaa = 0.4775` from the data.
- `R0`  against `betas` and `gammaa` instead of `gammaa` and `betas`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{alphaa = 0.4775, alphau = 0.695, mu = 0.062, qi = 0.078, 
  etai = 0.009, etau = 0.05};
R0 = (betas*alphaa)/(gammaa + mu) + (betas*alphau*
      gammaa*(1 - qi))/((gammaa + mu)*(etau + mu));
```

```
Show[Plot3D[R0, {betas, 0, 0.4}, {gammaa, 0, 0.4}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  BoxRatios -> 1/GoldenRatio, ViewPoint -> {-2, -3, 1}], 
 Plot3D[{1, 2}, {betas, 0, 0.4}, {gammaa, 0, 0.4}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, RGBColor[1, .1, 1]}, Mesh -> None, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your description is not too clear. I assume, according to the picture, that you want to plot R0 against gammaa and betas:

```
Plot3D[{R0, 1, 2}, {gammaa, 0, 0.4}, {betas, 0, 0.4}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"gamma", "betas", "R0"}, 
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]